# HTML javascript function call

Tags: javascript

Can someone tell me why is the call to my function hideShow not working ?

```
<a id='plusMinus0' href='#' title='Afficher la liste des messages d erreurs' onclick='hideShow(0);'>

function hideShow(number){
     alert("i am here");
     $('#errMsgGroup'+number).toggle('slow', function() {
         if($('#plusMinus'+number).children('img').attr('src').indexOf('images/NORIA_minus.JPG') >= 0){
                $('#plusMinus'+number).children('img').attr('src', 'images/NORIA_plus.JPG');
                $('#plusMinus'+number).children('img').attr('title', 'hide errors');        
            }
            else{
                $('#plusMinus'+number).children('img').attr('src', 'images/NORIA_minus.JPG');
                $('#plusMinus'+number).children('img').attr('title', 'show errors');
            }
        });
     }
```

Comment: Is your JS code inside `<script>` tags?

Comment: Are there any error messages in the Javascript console?

Comment: It might be worth posting a more complete version of your html and Javascript.

Comment: Yes my js is inside <script> tags, No errors in the consols. I am not even getting the alert "i am here", something is wrong with the i am calling it

Comment: The `alert` shows up fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/GYM38/. We simply don't have enough information to help you. Please provide a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @ Felix Kling "<strong style='color: red;'>Mise à jour impossible.<a id='plusMinus0' href='#' title='Afficher la liste des messages d erreurs' onclick='hideShow(0);'><img src='images/plus.JPG'/></a></strong><br><div id ='errMsgGroup0' style='display: none;'><font color=red>"+ctrlModif+"</font></div>";

Comment: Still shows the `alert` for me, even with the new markup: http://jsfiddle.net/GYM38/1/. If you want useful help, create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo with the problem.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pv33P/2/

Comment: created the JS fiddle Above

Comment: Well, the problem in the fiddle is that the function is defined inside the load event handler. That means it cannot be found by the inline event handler. The console shows the error `ReferenceError: hideShow is not defined`. Change `onLoad` in the select box to `No wrap - in <head>`. Since you said earlier that you don't get an error, I wonder if this is really the issue or you just didn't know how to use jsfiddle properly.

Answer (score 1):

put your function within `<script></script>` tag

Like

```
<script>


function hideShow(number){
     alert("i am here");
     $('#errMsgGroup'+number).toggle('slow', function() {
         if($('#plusMinus'+number).children('img').attr('src').indexOf('images/NORIA_minus.JPG') >= 0){
                $('#plusMinus'+number).children('img').attr('src', 'images/NORIA_plus.JPG');
                $('#plusMinus'+number).children('img').attr('title', 'hide errors');        
            }
            else{
                $('#plusMinus'+number).children('img').attr('src', 'images/NORIA_minus.JPG');
                $('#plusMinus'+number).children('img').attr('title', 'show errors');
            }
        });
     }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to close your A-tag as well like `<a id='plusMinus0' href='#' title='Afficher la liste des messages d erreurs' onclick='hideShow(0);'>hide / show</a>`

Comment: If you think that's the problem than you should also mention that JavaScript code belongs inside `<script>` tags.

Comment: MY FUNCTION IS INSIDE THE SCRIPT TAGS ,AND MY a TAG IS CLOSED AS WELL I JUST DIDNT POST IT.

Comment: @user2515601: How are we supposed to know that? Maybe you should post a more complete code example.

Comment: @FelixKling Sorry, it was a reply after someone else already mentioned that the function should be within the script blocks. That's why I didn't mention it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @sonusindhu and @putvande answers. You probably want a `return false` at the end of your javascript.

```
function hideShow(number){
  alert("i am here");
  $('#errMsgGroup'+number).toggle('slow', function() {
    if($('#plusMinus'+number).children('img').attr('src').indexOf('images/NORIA_minus.JPG') >= 0){
    $('#plusMinus'+number).children('img').attr('src', 'images/NORIA_plus.JPG');
       $('#plusMinus'+number).children('img').attr('title', 'hide errors');        
    }
    else{
      $('#plusMinus'+number).children('img').attr('src', 'images/NORIA_minus.JPG');
      $('#plusMinus'+number).children('img').attr('title', 'show errors');
    }
  });
  return false;
}
```

Comment: OK GUYS, i found out what was causing the problem.
It turned out that i have some parasite characters in my php file, some sort of ^M which i was only able to see with a cat -v, i looked it up on the net and found that by doing a dos2unix command on the files in question u delete all the undesired chars. It worked out for me.
THANK YOU ALL FOR YOUR TIME.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a id='plusMinus0' href='#' onclick="hideShow(0)">Test</a>

<script>
  function hideShow(number) {
     alert(number);
  }
</script>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pv33P/)

EDIT:

I think it's more elegant to handle the event with JQuery:

[with JQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/emvpZ/2/)

```
<a id='plusMinus0' href='#'>Test</a>

<script>
    $(function() {
       $("#plusMinus0").click(function() {
           alert("pass parameter from an attribute " + $(this).attr("id"))
       });
    });
</script>
```

With # in href, after click your anchor navigates to top of page, to avoid this:

```
<a id='plusMinus0' href='javascript:;'>Test</a>
```

or leave the href attribute:
    [Without href](http://jsfiddle.net/emvpZ/4/)

Comment: If you use jQuery, then you should remove `onclick="hideShow(0)"`.

Comment: I am using the onclick bc i have multiple PLUSes so i need to pass a variable in the function definition.

Comment: ok, it's your choice, but you can pass parameters via anchors attributes also.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pv33P/3/   can u please tell why this simple test is not working ?

Comment: Yes, on the left side change the framework extension "on load"=> no wrap - in head http://jsfiddle.net/pv33P/6/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function hideShow(number) {
            alert("i am here");
            $('#errMsgGroup' + number).toggle('slow', function () {
                if ($('#plusMinus' + number).children('img').attr('src').indexOf('images/NORIA_minus.JPG') >= 0) {
                    $('#plusMinus' + number).children('img').attr('src', 'images/NORIA_plus.JPG');
                    $('#plusMinus' + number).children('img').attr('title', 'hide errors');
                }
                else {
                    $('#plusMinus' + number).children('img').attr('src', 'images/NORIA_minus.JPG');
                    $('#plusMinus' + number).children('img').attr('title', 'show errors');
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a id='plusMinus0' href='#' title='Afficher la liste des messages d erreurs' onclick='hideShow(0);'>Check</a>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: i am still not getting my alert :/

Comment: I already checked it, I get alert. Once see for console errors, or else copy the html I have given into a sample page and run it you will get the alert :)